# checking user roles and navigate them to different pages while login in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

To distinguish users from each other in Firestore, I've assigned them boolean values. For example, if a user is a seller, then seller = true, productManager = false. If a user is a productManager,then seller=false, productManager=true. In all other cases, user is a customer. [image]

After Firebase authentication, i want to read this data and redirect them to different home screens (For example, if user is productManager, then redirect user to '/productManager_home' page.). My code is below. When "login" button is clicked, it calls the logIn function. I have tried many things so far, but i could not find a way to redirect multiple users from a single login button.

```
    void logIn() async {
        setState((){
          processing = true;
        });
        if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
          try{
            await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    
    
    
            _formKey.currentState!.reset();
    
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/customer_home');
          } on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
            if(e.code == 'user-not-found'){
              setState((){
                processing = false;
              });
              MyMessageHandler.showSnackBar(_scaffoldkey, 'No user found for that email.');
            }else if(e.code == 'wrong-password'){
              setState((){
                processing = false;
              });
              MyMessageHandler.showSnackBar(_scaffoldkey, 'Wrong password provided for that user.');
            }
          }
        } else {
          setState((){
            processing = false;
          });
          MyMessageHandler.showSnackBar(_scaffoldkey, 'Please fill all fields');
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done the first step of distinguishing them by assigning those property, so the next thing to do it, after successful login, get the userdata from Firestore, then check.

```
if (user['productManager'] == true) {
   // navigate to product manager home page
} else if (user['seller'] == true) {
   // navigate to seller home page
} else {
   // show an alert saying invalid login.
}
```

Comment: i tried to use var firebaseUser =  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(firebaseUser.uid).get();

Comment: but i get some errors while getting data from firestore, how to use collection reference, or how to get user['seller'] data?

Comment: can you show your code where you are getting the current user and data from fire store?

Answer (score 0):

There can be cases where you would also be searching the roles inside different collections, below code will work for that too:

```
Future<String?> getCurrentUserUid() async {
print("Getting User ID");
final User? user = _auth.currentUser;
if (user != null) {
  print("Somebody Logged In");
  return user.uid;
}

return null;}
```

So this function will get the user who is logged in.

```
Future<void> getUserRole(String? uid) async {
try {
  // Check the "users" collection for user role
  DocumentSnapshot userDoc =
  await _firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).get();
  role = userDoc.get("role");
  if (role != null) {
    // If role is found in the "users" collection, return it
    print(role);
    setState(() {});
    return;
  }
  userDoc = await _firestore.collection("clients").doc(uid).get();
  role = userDoc.get("role");
  if (role != null) {
    // If role is found in the "users" collection, return it
    print(role);
    setState(() {});
    return;
  }
  userDoc = await _firestore.collection("manager").doc(uid).get();
  role = userDoc.get("role");
  if (role != null) {
    // If role is found in the "users" collection, return it
    print(role);
    setState(() {});
    return;
  }
  // If the document doesn't exist or the role is not found, set role to null
  role = null;
  setState(() {});
} catch (e) {
  print("Error getting user role: $e");
  // If any error occurs, set role to null
  role = null;
  setState(() {});
}}
```

In here I am just trying to fetch roles from different collections, like if not a then b , not b then c, repeatable process.

```
Now Last step is to get it inside the FutureBuilder widget in Flutter is used to asynchronously build UI based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a Future.

FutureBuilder(
        future: getCurrentUserUid(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (role != null) {
              switch (role) {
                case 'User':
                  Future.microtask(() => Get.to(EmployeeDashboard()));
                  break;
                case 'Client':
                  Future.microtask(() => Get.to(CLientWelcomeScreen()));
                  break;
                case 'Manager':
                  Future.microtask(() => Get.to(ManagerWelcomeScreen()));
                  break;
                default:
                  return Container();
              }
            }
          else{
            Future.microtask(() => Get.to(LookingForScreen()));
          }
          return Container();
          }

      ),
```

And You are done.

Please remember, `Future.microtask(() => Get.to(EmployeeDashboard())` this is very important to use Future.microtask to navigate, or else it will throw debug lock error.

Don't worry, here is full code to copy-paste with a circular loading widget : [Happy Coding!!](https://pastebin.com/Myj1rNqL) Hope it helped!